# Tooltip CSS transition

Tags: javascript, css

Quero criar um `tooltip` (div hover na imagem) com CSS e `javascript`, utilizando `javascript` apenas para o estilo da `div`. Tenho o seguinte [exemplo em jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/70/)

Quero utilizar `transition` em `javascript` (DOM) como no seguinte exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/qrXyE/

Comment: Existe alguma restrição que seja necessário utilizar javascript para isso? Pois dependendo, é possível fazer utilizando somente css. Se realmente for necessário javascript, da para simplificar bastante seu código.

Comment: Sem CSS, so modificar o style com javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para funcionar a animação com o transition é necessário o estado inicial, então adicionei o `opacity: 0;` no html, depois é alterada para 1 via javascript. Veja o [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fp29n5x/).

Comment: @akm não sei se é só para mim, mas o tooltip fica "piscando" quando eu passo o mouse, adicionei `pointer-events: none;` no #div_legend e resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

Se vc não quiser desevolver do zero, te sugiro usar o CSS do Boostrap.

Vc só precisa adicionar esse CSS na sua página:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;

  line-break: auto;
}
.tooltip.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity: .9;
}
.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.tooltip.right {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.tooltip.bottom {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.tooltip.left {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.top-left .tooltip-arrow {
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.top-right .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-right-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.bottom-left .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
.tooltip.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

Chame o jquery e o javascript do bootstrap direto do CDN se não quiser copiar os arquivos.

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

E pronto.

no seus objetos HTML use classes e atributos do bootstrap. mais exemplos veja [aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

```
<div class="btn btn-default toolTipObj" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Teste tooltip na esquerda">Tooltip Esquerda</div>
```

Nota: não esqueça de inicilizar o tooltip em todos objetos da classe `toolTipObj` através de javascript.

```
$('.toolTipObj).tooltip(options)
```